# ANDROID OS Как перехватить все звуки системы?

Tags: android, ionic, ionicframework

В приложении нужна возможность захватывать звук системы, при этом воспроизведение на самом телефоне должно продолжаться, но с задержкой.
Можно ли это реализовать на ionic?